# Jquery Mobile First Page Load in AJAX

Tags: jquery-mobile

Im using JQueryMobile v1.2.0:

The flow of interaction with the webapp:

1. `home` page is entered in browser address bar. The home page have link to `page1`.
2. Clicking the link for `page1` will load the page via Ajax.
3. `page1` have link to `home` page. Clicking the link for `home` page will go to `home` page.

What I want is to load the `home` page via ajax when clicking the link in `page1`. I wasn't loaded via ajax since it is the first page that was loaded.

Comment: If you click on the link to 'home' in page1, does the event get fired (and fails), or is it because there is no event bound as the content was loaded after the DOM is ready? In that case use .live (or update handlers in the callback)

Comment: i also added `pageinit` $('#home-page').live('pageinit', function(event, data) but it is not fired.

Comment: Have you tried binding new events in the AJAX callback?